# Translate Two LineraLayout to each Other position in animation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-studio-3.0

```
ivSwapImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            frameFromX = llFrom.getX();
            frameFromY = llFrom.getY();
            frameToX = llTo.getX();
            frameToY = llTo.getY();
            if (isSwap) {
                llFrom.setX(frameToX);
                llFrom.setY(frameToY);
                llTo.setX(frameFromX);
                llTo.setY(frameFromY);
              isSwap = false;
            } else {
                llFrom.setX(frameToX);
                llFrom.setY(frameToY);
                llTo.setX(frameFromX);
                llTo.setY(frameFromY);
                isSwap = true;
            }
        }
    });`
```

Above write to change Two Linear layout swap to each other position.but need to add animation on that layouts
try this. how add an `animation` to `llFrom` and `llTo` LinearLayout?